# How can I read the data stored in EEPROM although is powered OFF based on the simple code I wrote?

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

I need help regarding on EEPROM library. Based on the code below, for every 2 sec, I want to store the int for `increase` where it will keep increasing by 1. Then, I upload to my Arduino Nano and open Serial Monitor to let it run for about 20 seconds. The serial monitor shows that `Increase Count:10`.

Then I unplug the Arduino Nano, closed the Serial Monitor, wait for 5 sec, then plug back to computer and turn on the Serial Monitor, then the Serial Monitor start to shows `Increase Count:1`, which indicated it start to recount again from 1,2,3,4.....

I thought that EEPROM will store the last number it counted which is 10, then when I unplug and plug back it should continue to count from 10, 11, 12, .......

So I would like to ask community whether my execution code and the method is correct or not. If not, can you advice me on how I can execute it correctly. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

int addr=5;
int storagedata;
int increase;

void setup() 
{
  storagedata=EEPROM.read(addr);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  timevalue=millis();
}

void loop() 
{
  if (millis()-timevalue>=2000)
  {
    increase=increase+1;
    
    EEPROM.update(addr,increase);
    storagedata=EEPROM.read(addr);

    Serial.print("Increase Count:");
    Serial.println(storagedata);

    timevalue=millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, true. That is why I need some guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`increase` is a global variable and will implicitly initialized with the value zero. Then you are reading the EEPROM data into the variable `storagedata` in `setup()`. And then in `loop()` you are increasing `increase` from zero to one and write that to EEPROM. This value then gets read back into `storagedata`. So now `increase` and `storagedata` have the same value: one. So the counting begins on every reset at 1.

It is unclear, why you even have 2 variables for this. One would be enough (unless you want to test the EEPROM for some reason). **In `setup()` read the data into `increase`.** Then the counting starts with the number in EEPROM.

Comment: strange what some people consider as useful answer

Comment: @Juraj I'm not sure, what you are criticizing here. Can you explain that a bit more? Is my answer not good in some way? Or is it about the fact, that such an easy answer gets more upvotes, as more complex ones? (Which I also wonder about)

Comment: I wonder how is the answer useful for anybody else then OP

Comment: @Juraj About that we could have a full discussion. Here we often have question, from whose answers others will most likely not profit. We have the possibility to dismiss those questions and close them, or answer them to help. Or - if you have an answer to the question, which would also help others - you can add your own answer.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for highlighting my error and I learned so much from your reply. Is fixed and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you fail to initialize `increase` during `setup()`. The variable is undefined when the code enters the `loop()` function, even regardless of whether this is the first boot or not. You should change `storagedata` to a local variable in loop() and use `increase` to keep the value (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

You never use the value you read in `setup()`.  Go through your `loop()` function one line at a time:

```c
// this does not use the value read in setup, variables are initialized to 0
// so the first time through this loop it will set 'increase' to 1
increase=increase+1;

// you are updating EEPROM with the value of 'increase' which is 1 the first
// time this is executed
EEPROM.update(addr,increase);

// you are reading the '1' that was just written into 'storagedata', you have
// never used the value you read in 'setup()' and have now overwritten it
storagedata=EEPROM.read(addr);
```

I'm not sure why you have two separate variables, but in `setup()` you just need to
initialize `increase` as the value read from EEPROM:

```c
storagedata=EEPROM.read(addr);
increase=storagedata; // start with stored value instead of default 0
```